# line continuation in .bib file URL for cleaner bibliography code

Tags: bibliographies, context

## Original question

Suppose I have the following in a bibliography file:

```
@misc{
  proofwiki,
  title={{Definition:Collation - ProofWiki}},
  author={{ProofWiki}},
  journal={{ProofWiki}},
  year={2021},
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "http://wiki.contextgarden.net"
        )
      ]
  }
}
```

I'm using ConTeXt to compile this file, and the URL inside the `\goto` command allows me to make sure that the bibliography entry has a live link inside the pdf.

Now, suppose I want to enforce clean code, with a max column 31 in the bib file. I tried breaking up the link as follows:

```
@misc{
  proofwiki,
  title={{Definition:Collation - ProofWiki}},
  author={{ProofWiki}},
  journal={{ProofWiki}},
  year={2021},
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "http://wiki.context"
          "garden.net"
        )
      ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, ConTeXt considers the line break in the `.bib` file a space in the actual URL. So I get a broken link in the PDF. I suppose the same goes for LaTeX in combination with `\href`.

How can I achieve line continuation without breaking the link?

## Edit

As requested, please find a MWE below:

### `test.tex`

```
\usebtxdefinitions[aps]
\usebtxdataset[bibliography.bib]
\setupinteraction[state=start]


\starttext
 
  \startbodymatter
    See \cite[proofwiki]
  \stopbodymatter

  \startbackmatter
    \startsection[title=Bibliography]
      \placelistofpublications
    \stopsection
  \stopbackmatter
\stoptext
```

### `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{
  proofwiki,
  title={{Definition:Collation - ProofWiki}},
  author={{ProofWiki}},
  journal={{ProofWiki}},
  year={2021},
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Language_of_Propositional_Logic"
        )
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It would be nice to have a self-contained MWE. You may try `\useURL [wiki] [http://contextgarden.net]` in your bibliography configuration file and call it as `\url[wiki]` in your `.bib` file.

Comment: @sztruks that's not really the solution I'm looking for. You could imagine having a URL so long it would overflow the desired number of columns in any ASCII file you dropped it into regardless of how short the preceding command would be. I would still need to break it up into multiple lines at some point. Please find MWE in edit to original question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that you are not just doing linebreak, you are converting one string to two stings!

```
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "http://wiki.contextgarden.net"
        )
      ]
  }
```

vs

```
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "http://wiki.context"
          "garden.net"
        )
      ]
  }
```

This would never work!

If you insert a literal line break, then it works[^1]

```
  howpublished={
    \goto
      {link}
      [
        url(
          "http://wiki.context
           garden.net"
        )
      ]
  }
```

[^1]: That depends a bit on the pdf viewer as well. I tested on zathura + firefox, which opens the link correctly.

Comment: I see absolutely no difference between your second and third examples. Furthermore it looks exactly the same as the code which didn't work in my question!

Comment: Pasted the wrong example. Try now

Comment: It works. Thanks.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at a very similar question here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639028/breaking-url-into-multiple-lines-results-in-broken-link-in-rendered-pdf). I tried applying the same approach as done in my bibliography above but it didn't work. Thanks!