# Breaking url into multiple lines results in broken link in rendered PDF

Tags: context, urls, links

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638541/line-continuation-in-bib-file-url-for-cleaner-bibliography-code), and with @Aditya's help I was able to break up URLs into multiple lines in my bibliography source file and still get the link to work.

Now, I would like to do the same in my source .tex file, so I tried something similar as shown in the answer provided by @Aditya:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext
\useURL
  [myUrl]
  [
    "https://www.g
    oogle.com"
  ]
\goto{link}[url(myUrl)]
\stoptext
```

Unfortunately the link does not work. When I *don't* split the URL into multiple lines, the link works again.

In reality my link is very long and forces uncomfortable line continuation in my `vim` editor. How can I break up long URLs in my source `.tex` file and still get the link to work in the resulting pdf?

Comment: It could be nice to mention that you are [crossposting](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2022/105372.html).

Comment: Yes... is that a bad thing?

Comment: Well, it might lead to a waste of people's time, so in that sense it is a bad thing. But if one is open with it, then potential answer writers could decide not to reply if there is already a good-enough answer.

Comment: The ConTeXt community being not so large, I have found it takes roughly 4 - 8 hours to get a response for these sorts of questions. I try to make up for it by looking up other resources like the ConTeXt garden and a number of books, but at the end of the day cross-posting helps give a question more exposure. Furthermore if I find the answer beforehand I make sure to update the stackexchange post. For example:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639024/clickable-link-for-simple-pdf-document-using-context

Comment: cross-posting is not the problem, but be open about it.  Mention the cross post (and if possible link to the other posting) directly.

Comment: Will do from now on. I understand what you mean. Thanks @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably ending lines where things are broken across lines with a character of category code 14(comment), usually `%`, and not nesting things between quotes, does the trick:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext
\useURL
  [myUrl]
  [%
    https://www.g%
    oogle.com%
  ]
\goto{link}[url(myUrl)]
\stoptext
```